# Alternative Mytrack for Android

Tags: android

I want to create an app for recording my jogging/walking routes similar to my tracks app (http://www.google.com/mobile/mytracks/). I want to record locations, display it in Google maps and exchange with other users.
I need to begin from something, like a plan. 
How should i start? Or at least can any one suggest what i will have need to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's some of the things you will need to learn how to do:

- Get the current location from your device GPS
- Store multiple locations into a path, filtering out noise and reducing the number of points to a reasonable amount
- Draw a polygon on a Google Maps view representing your route
- Web service to receive tracks under your account and store them in a database
- A login system for the web service (this could be a whole post in itself)
- A way to choose your "friends" on the web service so you can interact with other selected users
- Integration with Google Maps on the web site to show other people's routes

That's just off the top of my head, I'm sure you'll discover more as you clarify your ideas in your mind.

Comment: Thanks for response Greg. What about database, is it possible to store maps in a SQL db or it is possible to make it in a XML ?

Comment: You could do either. I know [PostgreSQL](http://postgresql.org) has a lot of GIS features that may specifically help in storing map track data.

Answer (score 3):

for gps location:

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000L, 5.0f, this);

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if (location != null) {
        double lat = location.getLatitude();
        double lng = location.getLongitude();
        GeoPoint myCurPos = new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1000000), (int) (lng * 1000000));
    }
}
```

to stop updates:

```
lm.removeUpdates(this);
```

use `MapView` and `ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem>` for google maps

Answer (score 1):

first, you should decide the features of your app. i think your app must have:

- a route which shaped a line
- speeding up and speeding down moments (you can calculate distance between two points and compare next and last calculates)
- big buttons (tired persons hands falters)

these are my first opinions.